# Enrich a caught Error and rethrow in angular/typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, error-handling

I am new to frontend development - I used to be backend only for last years. I am trying to remove a error-silencer in a helper and rethrow the swallowed error with more informations. In the custom ErrorHandler I will catch the error end send the information to a backend service. I do not know how to do this in the correct way. 
The throwing part (simplified):

```js
class Helper {
  public doStuff(input: string): string {
    try {
      return mightThrowAnException(input);
    } catch (err) {
      (err as any).inputData = input; // this destroys the error data
      throw err;
    }
  }
}
```

And catch this with

```js
export class GlobalErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

  constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
  ) {
    super();
  }

  public handleError(error: Error) {
    let loggingData: any = {
      errorMessage: error.message,
    }

    if (typeof (error as any).inputData !== "undefined") { // would like to replace this duck-typing, too
      loggingData = {
        ...loggingData,
        inputData: (error as any).inputData,
      }
    }

    // ... more stuff here

    console.log(loggingData); // will send the data to the logging server ITRL
  }
}
```

To enrich the error I already tried to use `@jsdevtools/ono` package:

```
class HelperWithOno {
  public doStuff(input: string): string {
    try {
      return mightThrowAnException(input);
    } catch (err) {
      throw ono(err, {inputData: input});
    }
  }
}
```

Which did the job. Unfortunately the TS linter does not like the usage of `symbol` ( https://github.com/JS-DevTools/ono/issues/13 ) so I *get a red build-pipeline*.

In PHP with Zend I would create a class which extends the general `Exception` in the namespace of the helper and add the `inputData` property. Then I would be able to check the type of the caught exception and handle it in the desired way.

But I am pretty new to angular and TypeScript and not sure how to perform this task.

- I could extend the `Error` class but

  - would I need to copy each property from the "previous" error manually? Or should I introduce another property `previousError` to store the original error?
  - where (directory) store the class-file?
  - should I create an injectable factory for the errors?
  - in which module would a experienced developer assume this class?
- Wait till `ono` is fixed
- Any other best practices?

Comment: BTW: I used https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fgvbck to write the sources for this post.

Comment: What is the purpose of this error handler? What prevents you from sending the error from the `catch` to a service that does all the handling? I also highly encourage not to trick typescript when it comes to typings, create an interface that holds your input and the error.

Comment: The calling function (caller) might be aware of the error and could catch the exception. If the caller (decides to) not catch the exception the global ErrorHandler should log the failure.

Comment: I woulod like to create the interface but do not know where to place the file for this purpose correctly (that is the reason behind the question _where (directory) store the class-file?_ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no answer so I just post my solution; hope someone will tell me if it is wrong/buggy and propose a better solution.

I created a folder with the name `errors` in the the directory of the class `Helper`. In this directory is a file with the class

```js
export class ProcessError extends Error {
    public inputData: string;
    public originalError: Error;

    public constructor(error: Error, inputData: string) {
        const errorAsAny = error as any;

        if ('fileName' in errorAsAny) {
            // Firefox specific
            if ('lineNumber' in errorAsAny) {
                // @ts-ignore
                super(error.message, errorAsAny.filename, errorAsAny.lineNumber);
            } else {
                // @ts-ignore
                super(error.message, errorAsAny.filename);
            }
        } else {
            super(error.message);
        }

        // Let's apply some magic you can find at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Breaking-Changes.md#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, ProcessError.prototype);

        this.originalError = error;
        this.inputData = inputData;
        this.stack = error.stack.split('\n').join('\n'); // materialize stack; not sure whether required
    }
}
```

Now I am able to throw the exception with

```js
class HelperWithCustomError {
  public doStuff(input: string): string {
    try {
      return mightThrowAnException(input);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new ProcessError(err, input);
    }
  }
}
```

and check for the instance instead of duck-typing with

```js
if (error instnaceof ProcessError)
```

Comment: For anyone coming along and wondering, this is indeed the correct way to enrich errors in javascript / typescript.